# powershell cannot bind parameter 'NewPassword'

Tags: python, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to write a program that changes the user's Windows password using a PowerShell command in Python.

I tried this.

```
import subprocess

password = input('Enter New Password: ')

c1 = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
c2 = "Set-ADAccountPassword john -NewPassword " + password + " –Reset".format(password)

c = subprocess.call([c1, c2])

print (c)
```

But it gives an error

```
Set-ADAccountPassword : Cannot bind parameter 'NewPassword'.  Cannot convert the "mynewpass1" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
```

I read on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-5.1 that you you have convert plain strings to secure strings with a command such as this.

```
PS C:\> $Secure_String_Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssW0rD!" -AsPlainText -Force
```

I tried rewriting my program but I get an invalid syntax error.  Is it even possible to do this?
Here is what I am working with now.

```
import subprocess

password = input('Enter New Password: ')


a1, a2 = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "$PwdVar = ConvertTo-SecureString "{0}" -AsPlainText -Force; Set-ADAccountPassword jm09580 -NewPassword $PwdVar –Reset"
c = subprocess.call([a1, a2.format(password)])

print (c)
```

Comment: `"$PwdVar = ConvertTo-SecureString "{0}" -AsPlain..."` -> `"$PwdVar = ConvertTo-SecureString '{0}' -AsPlain..."`

Comment: If you use unescaped double quotes inside a double-quoted string you're getting 2 separate strings with a (most likely invalid) expression between them.

Comment: That ran but it looks like it locked me out of my account and new password doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check (i.e. display) the command you were running before actually running it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that your quotes are not being escaped properly. You need quotes in the correct place for the command line arguments and then for the variables. It gets quite messy.

PowerShell has a feature to help with this, You can pass it a script as a Base64 encoded string. It will contain no special characters to escape.

I have next to no Python skills and I haven't tested this example, Its just to help you get on the right track:

```
import base64
a1, a2 = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "$PwdVar = ConvertTo-SecureString "{0}" -AsPlainText -Force; Set-ADAccountPassword jm09580 -NewPassword $PwdVar –Reset"
data = base64.b64encode(a2.format(password))
c = subprocess.call([a1, '-EncodedCommand ' + data])
```

What your command should look like is this basically:

```
PowerShell -EncodedCommand MQAuAC4AMQAwACAAfAAgACUAIAB7ACAAIgBQAG8AdwBlAHIAUwBoAGUAbABsACAAUgBvAGMAawBzACIAIAB9AA==
```

Powershell will decode the string and run the commands inside.